# associativity of multipication of natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, natural-numbers

I am trying to prove by induction the associativity of natural numbers. It is easy to see that if $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$, then $(mn)1=m(n1)$. If $p\in \mathbb{N}$ is such that $(mn)p= m(np)$, then $(mn)(p+1)=(mn)p+mn=m(np)+mn=m[np+n]=m(n(p+1)).$ But I am using the distributivity property here. Is that possible? Those properties should be independent.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What axioms are you taking for granted here? That is, what are you assuming?

Comment: @mixedmath:  $n+(p+1) = (n+p)+1$ and $n(p+1)=np+n$.

Comment: Usually it is assumed that a(b+1)=ab+a as part of the definition of multiplication, how is multiplication defined here?

Comment: You're talking about the associativity of MULTIPLICATION OF natural numbers.  Simply to speak of "the associativity of natural numbers", rather than the associativity of some binary operation on natural numbers, is nonsense.  And often one considers _addition_ of natural numbers as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you write (mn)(p+1)=mn+mn+mn+..+mn (p+1)factors 
which is the definition of multiplication you get mn(p+1)=(mn)p+mn (without using the distribitivity)
you can use the hypothesis of induction .thus
mn(p+1)=m(np)+mn=m(np+n)(by the definition of multiplication and identification)
so mn(p+1)=m(n(p+1))
and you can conclude.